# algorithm to find all the coordinate points of right angle triangle on grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, geometry, graph-algorithm

I am placing right angle triangle on grid and I have to find all the coordinate points which lies within the region of that right angle triangle. So is there any algorithm for doing that.

Thank you

Comment: place the triangle 90 deg angle on the (0,0), then create a function that find you the hypotenuse of the triangle at position y when given x as input, for example: f(x) = y, after those two easy taks you can decide for any point if it belongs to the triangle or not

Answer (score 0):

If the right angle has base x and height y, a coordinate point a,b lies in the triangle if 
**a < x** and **b < y** (provided the vertice containing right angle is at 0,0) .
 So check for all a,b in that manner. Other wise if the orintation is different it is way more complicated...